# Почему isinstance() так странно работает?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Приведу пример на очень простом коде:

```
a = 30
b = True
print(type(a), type(b))
print(isinstance(b, type(a)))
print(isinstance(a, type(b)))
```

И имеем вот такой вот вывод:

```
<class 'int'> <class 'bool'>
True
False
```

Собственно, появился вопрос, почему в первом случае `isinstance()` выдает `True`?
И что можно сделать, что бы он выдавал `False`, т.к. IDE не рекомендует использовать данную конструкцию:

```
if type(a) == type(b):
    pass
```

Версия *Python* - 3.9.8

Comment: `bool` является подтипом `int` в Питоне. Ваш эксперимент это подтверждает. А теперь расскажите нам что вы хотите сделать на самом деле.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888620/comparing-boolean-and-int-using-isinstance

Comment: А конкретная формулировка какая вот у этого "IDE не рекомендует использовать данную конструкцию"? Я подозреваю, что там не совсем так написано. Вы вообще с какой целью классы сравниваете у себя в коде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(int.__subclasses__())
```

Вывод:

```
[<class 'bool'>, <enum 'IntEnum'>, <enum 'IntFlag'>, <class 'sre_constants._NamedIntConstant'>, <class 'pyasn1.type.univ.SizedInteger'>, <class 'grpc._channel._InitialMetadataFlags'>]
```

Так что `isinstance` работает согласно своему описанию:

> **isinstance(object, classinfo)** Return True if the object argument is an
> instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, indirect, or
> virtual) subclass thereof.

Вообще смысл проверки через `isinstance(a, b)` в том, можно ли использовать объект `a` в том месте, где требуется объект класса `b`. И таки да: `bool` вполне можно использовать там, где требуется `int`, на этом построено довольно много разных трюков с кодом, позволяющих писать короткий и понятный код за счёт такого использования. Но наоборот использовать `int` там где требуется `bool` - ну, в принципе, можно, но не всегда, и вторая проверка об этом вам и говорит.